# Let $V$ be a real vector space and $E$ be an idempotent linear operator on $V$. Prove that $I + E$ is invertible.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, proof-explanation, idempotents

Let $V$ be a real vector space and $E$ be an idempotent linear operator on $V$, that is a projection. Prove that $I + E$ is invertible. Find $(I + E) ^{-1}$

**My teacher taught me the following proof for the proposition**

Since $E$ is an idempotent linear operator it is
diagonalizable. **So there exists a basis of $V$
consisting of characteristics vectors of $E$ corresponding to the
characteristic values $0$ and $1$**. That is, there exists a basis $\beta = \{ \beta_1, ....,\beta_n \}$  such that $E\beta_i = \beta_i$
for $i = 1, · · · , k$,  and
$E\beta_i = 0$ for $i = k + 1, · · · , n$.

Then $(I + E)\beta_i = 2\beta_i$
for
$i = 1, · · · , k$ and $(I + E)\beta_i = \beta_i$
for $i = k + 1, · · · , n$, that is,

$$[I + E]\beta = 
\begin{bmatrix}
    2I_1    &0 \\
    0 & I_2\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

where $I_1$ stands for $k × k$ identity matrix, $I_2$ is $(n − k) × (n −
k)$ identity matrix and each $0$ represents the zero matrix of
appropriate dimension. It is now easy to see that $[I + E]\beta$ is
invertible,  since $det(I + E) = 2k \not=0$

To find the inverse of $(I + E)$, we note that

$$([I + E]_\beta)^{-1} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
    \frac{I_1}{2}    &0 \\
    0 & I_2\\
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
    I_1    &0 \\
    0 & I_2\\
\end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix}
    \frac{-I_1}{2}    &0 \\
    0 & 0\\
\end{bmatrix} = I-\frac{1}{2}[E]_\beta$$

Therefore, $(I + E)
^{−1} = I −\frac{1}{2}E$

**But I do not understand very well the following sentence:**

*So there is a basis of $ V $
consisting of characteristics vectors of $ E $ corresponding to the
characteristic values ​​$ 0 $ and $ 1 $*

My question is, **why the characteristic values ​​are $1$ and $0$?**

Comment: Because if $x$ is a characteristic vector with characteristic value $\lambda$ for $E$, then $x$ is a characteristic vector with characteristic value $\lambda^2$ for $E^2$. But since $E^2=E$, then $\lambda^2=\lambda$.

Comment: I didn’t know that « characteristic vector » was a standard denomination for « eigenvector ». What is the most common one in English ?

Comment: Eigenvalue and eigenvector

Comment: @Adren: Eigenvector/eigenvalue are the most common, but “characteristic vector” and “characteristic value” are not unheard of.

Comment: For $I=0$ the formula for $(I+E)^{-1}$ is not true. The last part of the line $([I + E]_\beta)^{-1} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
    \frac{I_1}{2}    &0 \\
    0 & I_2\\
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
    I_1    &0 \\
    0 & I_2\\
\end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix}
    \frac{-I_1}{2}    &0 \\
    0 & 0\\
\end{bmatrix} = I-\frac{1}{2}[E]_\beta$ is incorrect.

Comment: @JensSchwaiger $I$ is the standard identity matrix. For $M_2(\mathbb{R})$ it would be $\begin{bmatrix} 1&0 \\ 0&1 \\ \end{bmatrix}$

Comment: I mixed the notions. For me $E$ Idee to be the identity matrix. I'm sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a short proof:

Let $u=I+E$. Since $E^2=E$, we have $u^2=I+2E+E^2=I+3E=3u-2I$

This can be rewritten as :

$uv=I$ where $v=\frac{1}{2}(3I-u)$

Which proves that $u$ is invertible and $u^{-1}=\frac{1}{2}(2I-E)$

Answer (score 2):

$$EE=E$$
$$Ex=\lambda x$$
$$EEx=E(Ex)=E(\lambda x)=\lambda^2 x$$
$$EEx=Ex$$
$$\lambda^2 x = \lambda x$$
$$(\lambda-1)\lambda x = 0$$
Since an eigenvector $x$ cannot be zero, we get $\lambda=0$ or $\lambda=1$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this explanation:

E is an idempotent operator on V $\space \Leftrightarrow \space \space $  E$^2$ = E $\space \space \Leftrightarrow \space$ E is a projection operator on V having range say R and null space say N.

Then we have, $\beta \in R \Leftrightarrow E\beta$ = $\beta$,and V = R $\oplus$ N
... $\mathtt result$

(clearly, $\beta \in N \Leftrightarrow E\beta =0$ )

So, if $\mathscr B_R =${ $\beta_1,...,\beta_k $} is an ordered basis of R and $\mathscr B_N =${ $\beta_{k+1},...,\beta_n $} is an ordered basis of N, then $\mathscr B $= { $\mathscr B_R, \mathscr B_N $ } = {$\beta_1,...,\beta_k, \beta_{k+1},...,\beta_n  $} is an ordered basis of V = R $\oplus$ N, where, $E_{\beta_i} = \beta_i \mathit \space for\space i = 1,...,k $ and
$E_{\beta_i} = 0  \mathit \space for \space i = k+1,...,n.$

It is trivial that range R is a characteristic space and it corresponds to the characteristic value 1, null space N is a characteristic space and it corresponds to the characteristic value 0.

[ Let me know if you want a short proof of the $\mathtt result$. The problem that I have from the above mentioned reasoning is that one can in a similar way derive that $\mathit EEEx = Ex \Rightarrow (\lambda^2 - 1)\lambda x = 0 \Rightarrow \lambda = 0, 1$ or $ -1 $(and so on).

Let me know what you think. ]

Thank You!